# Receiving Error Message in ionic App from PHP file on Post Request

Tags: php, ionic-framework, ionic3

It is required to add the product to the MySql Database (remote)
by the ionicApp. There is a Product Page. When submit is pressed, the post method is called from the ionicApp "Product.ts" page by function `createEntry()`.
The record has been created successfully if there is no constraint error with the help of a PHP file named manage_products.php.
In the ionic app `if(data.status === 200)` is `true` then the body get executed. But there is no way if the record has been created or not. if there is some problem, for example, some `null` constraint (Db side) then it is only via the Chrome network tab that I come to know about some constraint error. Is there any way to receive error text from the PHP file in the ionic App.

Here is the function to `createEntry` called from ionicApp "Product.ts"

```
createEntry()
 {
     let id = "0000";
     let name = "Some Product";
     let description = "Some Product description";
     let manufacturer_name = "manufacturer_name";
     let weight = "some weight is here";
     let weight_unit = "kg";
     let halal_status = "HALAL";
      let body     : string   = "key=create&id=" + id + "&name=" + name + "&description=" + description + "&manufacturer_name=" + manufacturer_name + "&weight=" + weight + "&weight_unit=" + weight_unit +  "&halal_status=" + halal_status ,
          type     : string   = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
          headers  : any      = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': type}),
          options  : any      = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }),
          url      : any      = this.baseURI + "manage_products.php";

      this.http.post(url, body, options)
      .subscribe((data) =>
      {
         // If the request was successful notify the user
         if(data.status === 200)
         {
         //   this.hideForm   = true;

      console.log(`Congratulations the technology: ${name} was successfully added`);
      console.log('successfully added the record. .......');  
       }
         // Otherwise let 'em know anyway
         else
         {
           // this.sendNotification('Something went wrong!');
            console.log('Couldnt add the record.....xxx');  

        }


      });
   }
```

The above code is calling the PHP file. Here is the code for the PHP file.

```
<?php
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

   // Define database connection parameters

   $hn      = 'localhost';
   $un      = 'username';
   $pwd     = 'password';
   $db      = 'name-of-database';
   $cs      = 'utf8';

   // Set up the PDO parameters
   $dsn  = "mysql:host=" . $hn . ";port=3306;dbname=" . $db . ";charset=" . $cs;
   $opt  = array(
                        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ,
                        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
                       );
   // Create a PDO instance (connect to the database)
   $pdo  = new PDO($dsn, $un, $pwd, $opt);

   // Retrieve specific parameter from supplied URL
   $key  = strip_tags($_REQUEST['key']);
   $data    = array();


   // Determine which mode is being requested
   switch($key)
   {

      // Add a new record to the technologies table
      case "create":

         // Sanitise URL supplied values

         $id       = filter_var($_REQUEST['id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);
         $name       = filter_var($_REQUEST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);
         $manufacturer_name   = filter_var($_REQUEST['manufacturer_name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);
         $weight   = filter_var($_REQUEST['weight'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);
         $weight_unit       = filter_var($_REQUEST['weight_unit'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);
         $halal_status   = filter_var($_REQUEST['halal_status'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);
   $description   = filter_var($_REQUEST['description'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);


         // Attempt to run PDO prepared statement
         try {
            $sql  = "INSERT INTO Products(id,name,manufacturer_name,weight,weight_unit,halal_status,description) VALUES(:id, :name, :manufacturer_name, :weight, :weight_unit, :halal_status, :description)";
            $stmt    = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':manufacturer_name', $manufacturer_name, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
            $stmt->bindParam(':weight', $weight, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':weight_unit', $weight_unit, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':halal_status', $halal_status, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
            $stmt->bindParam(':description', $description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();
            echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Congratulations the record ' . $name . ' was added to the database'));
         }
         // Catch any errors in running the prepared statement
         catch(PDOException $e)
         {
            echo $e->getMessage();
         }

      break;


      // Update an existing record in the technologies table
      case "update":

         // Sanitise URL supplied values
  /*
         $name          = filter_var($_REQUEST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);
         $description   = filter_var($_REQUEST['description'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);
         $recordID      = filter_var($_REQUEST['recordID'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

*/   
         $id       = filter_var($_REQUEST['id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);
         $name       = filter_var($_REQUEST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);
         $manufacturer_name   = filter_var($_REQUEST['manufacturer_name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);
         $weight   = filter_var($_REQUEST['weight'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);
         $weight_unit       = filter_var($_REQUEST['weight_unit'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);
         $halal_status   = filter_var($_REQUEST['halal_status'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);

         // Attempt to run PDO prepared statement
         try {
            $sql  = "UPDATE Products SET id = :id, name = :name,manufacturer_name = :manufacturer_name,weight = :weight,weight_unit = :weight_unit,halal_status = : halal_status, description = :description WHERE id = :id";
            $stmt =  $pdo->prepare($sql);

           /*
            $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':description', $description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':id', $recordID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
           */
            $stmt->bindParam(':id', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':manufacturer_name', $description, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
            $stmt->bindParam(':weight', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':weight_unit', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':halal_status', $description, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
            $stmt->bindParam(':description', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $stmt->execute();

            echo json_encode('Congratulations the record ' . $name . ' was updated');
         }
         // Catch any errors in running the prepared statement
         catch(PDOException $e)
         {
            echo $e->getMessage();
         }

      break;



      // Remove an existing record in the technologies table
      case "delete":

         // Sanitise supplied record ID for matching to table record
         $recordID   =  filter_var($_REQUEST['id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

         // Attempt to run PDO prepared statement
         try {
            $pdo  = new PDO($dsn, $un, $pwd);
            $sql  = "DELETE FROM Products WHERE id = :id";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':id', $recordID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();

            echo json_encode('Congratulations the record ' . $name . ' was removed');
         }
         // Catch any errors in running the prepared statement
         catch(PDOException $e)
         {
            echo $e->getMessage();
         }

      break;
   }

?>
```

Comment: you can throw exception when an error occurs or you can send 500 status through header `header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
`

Answer (score 0):

you can  use the alertcontroller or toastcontroller and display the error message by adding a catch after you have subscribed to the data...like this

```
catch((err)=>{
          this.AlertMessage("error", err);
         });
```

Comment: please note that the AlertMessage function was created inside the class which uses the alertcontroller

Comment: AlertMessage(error_title,error_message){
    let alert = this.alert.create({
      title:error_title,
      message:error_message,
      buttons:['Dismiss']
    });
    alert.present();
  }